# Ploting in a wxFrame, How to pass an argument?

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

As example, consider the code in http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_wx4.html . But, supose that I need to pass the amplitude as argument, how can I do that? if a modify the App class declaration like

```
class App(wx.App):
    def __init__(self,amplitude):
        wx.App.__init__(self)
        self.arg=amplitude
    def OnInit(self):
        '''Create the main window and insert the custom frame'''
        frame = CanvasFrame(self.arg)
        frame.Show(True)

        return True
```

and if I modify the CanvasFrame.__init_ _() to acept an argument this doesn't work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you call `OnInit()` from `__init__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand why argument passing to `CanvasFrame` should not work. The linked mpl wx4 demo was modified as follows and it worked:
**EDIT II**: Your error was swapping `wx.App.__init__(self)` and `self.args = amplitude`. In your case `self.args` was not set yet when `App.OnInit(…)` gets called.

```
class CanvasFrame(wx.Frame):    
    def __init__(self, amplitude):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, …
        …
        self.amplitude = amplitude
        …
        # now use the amplitude
        s = sin(2*pi*t) * self.amplitude
```

In derived `App`:

```
class App(wx.App):
    def __init__(self, amplitude):
        self.amplitude = amplitude
        wx.App.__init__(self)

    def OnInit(self):
        'Create the main window and insert the custom frame'
        frame = CanvasFrame(self.amplitude)
        frame.Show(True)

        return True

amplitude = 16
app = App(amplitude)
app.MainLoop()
```

Probably it is not a good idea to have a `CanvasFrame` and `App` which cannot be initialised as a `wx.Frame` anymore (parent and title hardcoded into object), but this is another story.

EDIT: extended example to fully meet OP's question (argument passing from the top level inward.)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, in this example this works perfectly. But the real problem, where i need to do that is an spaguetti code and this don't works, but this is my fault, and I need to unravel it to know what is wrong. 

Thanks a lot :)